# Copying a sheet using Excel Interop to another file: how can I avoid generating absolute paths?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I'm using the `Excel Interop` library to copy a sheet from one Excel file to another.
This is the code I've developed for this:

```
public static void CopySheet()
{
    Application excellApp = new Application();
    excellApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
    excellApp.ScreenUpdating = false;

    var originWorkbook = excellApp.Workbooks.Open(originFile);
    var destWorkbook = excellApp.Workbooks.Open(destinationFile);
            
    var sheetToCopy = (Worksheet)originWorkbook.Sheets[1];
    sheetToCopy.Copy(destWorkbook.Sheets[1]);

    destWorkbook.Save();
    destWorkbook.Close();
    originWorkbook.Close();
    excellApp.Quit();
}
```

This code seems to work, however it has a serious problem with Pivot tables: if the sheet you're copying has a Pivot table, the table's data source expression gets changed.

For example, if the original sheet's table has this data source:

[image]

after copying, it becomes this:

[image]

What is happening is that an absolute path to the origin file is added to the data source.
I don't want this, how can I avoid this? I don't want any reference to be changed, I would like it to stay the same as in the original file.

As a workaround, I've found that I can loop through all the Pivot tables in the sheet and manually remove the absolute path from the `SourceData` property. However this seems hacky to me, and also I don't know if this only affects Pivot tables, it might also happen with other objects in the sheet that have a data source, like charts etc.

Is there a proper way to copy a sheet to another file without changing ANY references?

Comment: I tend to remove links by replacing the "=" with xyxy before copying a sheet to another file. This prevents any formulae or link updating itself to the original. After I replace the xyxy with = and it all works. For that table, I would not create yhat pivot table until after the vopy.

Comment: @SolarMike: unfortunately the requirement for the tool I'm writing is that it needs to import a sheet from one existing file into another existing file, regardless of what is inside, so I wanted to limit the amount of modifications that the tool does to a minum. At the moment, cycling through the pivots and patching the references seems less invasive to me than re-creating the pivots altogether as you suggest, bit thanks for the tip

Comment: Well I came up with my method when I had a madter sheet yhat referenced several thousand cells in 6 other workbooks. Good luck your way.